# How to normalize html before usemin

Tags: regex, gulp, gulp-usemin

Some of our devs have mac and some have PC - and there seems to be an issue with usemin when trying to run it - as whitespaces (CRLF and LF) are interchanging and messing it up.

Is there some kind of plugin or regex I can use in  my gulpfile to fix them before running usemin?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use regex, you can mention these:

- `\r` matches a carriage return (ASCII 13) or CR
- `\n` matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10) or LF

So you can find all CRLF by a simple regex like `/\r\n/g` and LF by `/\n/g` and replace them by something like `\r\n`.

To replace both of those types or also other combinations like CR or LFCR use this regex:

```
/[\r\n]/g
```

---

For more (by adding form feed character):

- `\f` matches a form-feed character (ASCII 12)

  ```
  /[\f\r\n]/g
  ```